# How to create Tensorflow serving_input_receiver_fn with multiple features?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

In the [TF guide on saving models](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/saved_model) there is a paragraph on serving_input_receiver_fn that talks about implementing functions for preprocessing logic.  I'm trying to do some normalization of input data for a DNNRegressor.  Their code for the function looks like this:

```
feature_spec = {'foo': tf.FixedLenFeature(...),
                'bar': tf.VarLenFeature(...)}

def serving_input_receiver_fn():
  """An input receiver that expects a serialized tf.Example."""
  serialized_tf_example = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.string,
                                         shape=[default_batch_size],
                                         name='input_example_tensor')
  receiver_tensors = {'examples': serialized_tf_example}
  features = tf.parse_example(serialized_tf_example, feature_spec)
  return tf.estimator.export.ServingInputReceiver(features, receiver_tensors)
```

My code looks like this:

```
feat_cols = [
    tf.feature_column.numeric_column(key="FEATURE1"),
    tf.feature_column.numeric_column(key="FEATURE2")
]

def serving_input_receiver_fn():
    feature_spec = tf.feature_column.make_parse_example_spec(feat_cols)

    default_batch_size = 1

    serialized_tf_example = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.string, shape=[default_batch_size], name='tf_example')

    receiver_tensors = { 'examples': serialized_tf_example}

    features = tf.parse_example(serialized_tf_example, feature_spec)

    fn_norm1 = lamba FEATURE1: normalize_input_data('FEATURE1', FEATURE1)
    fn_norm2 = lamba FEATURE2: normalize_input_data('FEATURE2', FEATURE2)
    features['FEATURE1'] = tf.map_fn(fn_norm1, features['FEATURE1'], dtype=tf.float32)
    features['FEATURE2'] = tf.map_fn(fn_norm2, features['FEATURE2'], dtype=tf.float32)

    return tf.estimator.export.ServingInputReceiver(features, receiver_tensors)
```

After all of that the saved model has none of my features in the graph.  I'm trying to figure out how this works if you have more than one feature you are trying to pass.

I created an example using the keras MPG data.  [It is located here](https://github.com/GeoffCraig/TF_MPG_Serving/blob/master/MPG_Example_Serving.ipynb):

Comment: Where is `receiver_tensors` defined?

Comment: Sorry, forgot that line.  receiver_tensors = { 'examples': serialized_tf_example}  I'll update the post

Comment: At one point I had `receiver_tensors` as a dict with the features defined.  The code didn't error but when I went to serving it threw an error saying that I needed to provide a value for tf_example.

Comment: You still haven't provided much context. Post a [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) code.

Comment: @SiyuanRen I created an example based on the keras MPG code but it has the same issue.  I need to know how to create a functional serving_input_receiver_fn to normalize data when using TF Serving's Web API.

Comment: What do you mean that the saved model has none of the features? Do you want to, say, feed the network not with an `tf.Example` proto, but separate 'Cylinders', 'Displacement', ... tensors?

Comment: I want to use the Tensorflow web api for predictions.  For other models I just pass a JSON document like so:   `{
 "signature_name": "predict",
 "instances":[{
  "Cylinders": [4.0],
  "Displacement": [140.0],
  "Horsepower": [86.0],
  "Weight": [2790.0],
  "Acceleration": [15.6],
  "Model_Year": [82.0],
  "USA": [1.0],
  "Europe": [0.0],
  "Japan": [0.0]
 }]
}`

Comment: However I get the error `{ "error": "Failed to process element: 0 key: Cylinders of \'instances\' list. Error: Invalid argument: JSON object: does not have named input: Cylinders" }`  I'm assuming that I'm either building the serving input function incorrectly or I need to change the JSON payload.  I just don't know which.  It would be _really_ helpful if there was an end to end example, I would think that anyone serving a regressor would have to do this.

Answer (score 0):

`features` in `ServingInputReceiver` is passed directly to your model function. What you want is `receive_tensors` or `receive_tensor_alternatives`, that is, the second and third argument to `ServingInputReceiver` constructor.

For example, you may do this

```
serialized_tf_example = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.string, shape=[default_batch_size], name='tf_example')

receiver_tensors = { 'examples': serialized_tf_example}

raw_features = tf.parse_example(serialized_tf_example, feature_spec)

fn_norm1 = lamba FEATURE1: normalize_input_data('FEATURE1', FEATURE1)
fn_norm2 = lamba FEATURE2: normalize_input_data('FEATURE2', FEATURE2)
features['FEATURE1'] = tf.map_fn(fn_norm1, raw_features['FEATURE1'], dtype=tf.float32)
features['FEATURE2'] = tf.map_fn(fn_norm2, raw_features['FEATURE2'], dtype=tf.float32)
return tf.estimator.export.ServingInputReceiver(
      features=features,
      receiver_tensors=receiver_tensors,
      receiver_tensors_alternatives={'SOME_KEY': raw_features})
```

If you don't ever need to feed the network with an `Example` proto, you can skip it entirely.

```
raw_features = {'FEATURE1': tf.placeholder(...), 'FEATURE2': tf.placeholder(...)}
features = preprepocess(raw_features)
return tf.estimator.export.ServingInputReceiver(features, {'SOME_OTHER_KEY': raw_features})
```